# Обработка событий элементов управления в ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет, есть некая WPF форма, в которой расположен элемент управления Canvas.

```
<Window x:Class="MyMap.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="My" Height="434.219" Width="650.781">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Canvas Name="myCanvas" MouseWheel="myCanvas_MouseWheel"></Canvas>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Собственно сам вопрос, как правильно обработать событие **MouseWheel** элемента управления **Canvas** в **ViewModel**?

Если с размещением обработчика события в **codebehind** **WPF** формы и реализации всей логики там все легко и понятно, то не совсем ясно как **правильно** (*т.е. чтобы это не противоречило канонам разработки WPF приложений и паттерну MVVM*) проделать все тоже самое, но только в **ViewModel**.

Comment: Когда мы говорим о MVVM, нужно отделять логику UI от логики программы (место которой — в VM).

Что именно должен делать обработчик `MouseWheel`? От этого зависит то, нужно выносить эту обработку в VM или нет.

Comment: В обработчике MouseWheel отслеживается движение колеса мыши над элементом Canvas и зависимости от того в какую строну была прокрутка (вверх/низ), осуществляется зуммирование отображенного в канвасе элемента (некой картинки).

Comment: @sp7, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @VladD, еще несколько вопросов. Предположим свой ZoomControl контрол я создал, определил у него свойство ZoomLevel. Далее я хочу при изменении свойства ZoomLevel выполнять какую-то логику в VM (в моем случае изменять картинку). Как это правильно делать и где должна располагаться логика во VM. В методе доступа set у свойства ZoomLevel или нет?

Comment: @sp7: Например, там. В `set` свойства VM вы можете запускать дополнительную логику. Не забудьте вынести её в отдельный метод, а не писать километровый `set`.

Comment: @VladD, если я правильно  понял, это может выглядеть так?

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
         private int _zoomLevel;

         public int ZoomLevel 
         { 
            get { return _zoomLevel; }

            set 
            {
                _zoomLevel = value;
                 // Сигнализируем системе об изменении свойства.
                 OnPropertyChanged("ZoomLevel");

                 // Некий метод, который обновляет картинку
                 this.UpdateImage(_zoomLevel);
            }
         }
    }

Comment: @sp7: Именно так.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за помощь! Вы мне помогли! Буду обращаться при необходимости ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В обработчике MouseWheel отслеживается движение колеса мыши над элементом Canvas и зависимости от того в какую строну была прокрутка (вверх/низ), осуществляется зуммирование отображенного в канвасе элемента (некой картинки).

Отлично. Давайте подумаем, что является *смыслом* всей этой логики? Ответ: это установление zoom level'а.

Теперь у нас есть две возможности, которая из них правильная — выбирать вам, как архитектору приложения.

Возможно, что zoom level — это лишь подробность отображения картинки, не имеющая к логике программы никакого отношения. Тогда zoom level не выносится во ViewModel, а остаётся внутри View.

Вторая возможность — это если zoom level интересен и остальной части программы, а не только этому view. Тогда мы должны поместить свойство `ZoomLevel` в VM.

В обоих случаях нам нужно привязать переменную типа `double` так, чтобы она увеличивалась или уменьшалась в зависимости от прокрутки колеса мыши. Эту логику удобно не писать «вручную» в контроле, содержащем `Canvas`, а вынести в отдельный невидимый `UserControl`. Или (лучше!) вы можете вынести её в отдельный `Behaviour` (читайте [здесь](http://sonyks2007.blogspot.com/2013/11/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction.html), [здесь](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/01/attached-behaviours-in-wpf/), а [здесь](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2009/04/using-a-behavior-to-magnify-your-wpf-applications/) упоминается уже существующее `ZoomBehavior`).

В любом случае у вас будет либо `UserControl`, либо `Behavior`, который/ое будет ловить событие `MouseWheel` и обновлять через `Binding` свойство `ZoomLevel`, которое лежит либо внутри View, либо в VMб в зависимости от вашей архитектуры.

Зуммирование картинки теперь легко осуществить, привязавшись к свойству `ZoomLevel`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, т.е. я правильно понимаю, что в случае UserControl я фактически делаю следующее:

1) Создаю свой элемент управления, например MyCanvas, который наследуется от базового Canvas. 

2) Далее в MyCanvas я реализую свойство ZoomLevel, как свойство зависимости, и вычисляю его в codebehind данного канваса.

3) Затем моя VM биндится к данному свойству ZoomLevel моего канваса.

Comment: @sp7: Я имел в виду такой вариант: вы наследуетесь от `UserControl` (пусть будет `ZoomControl`), в `ZoomControl` определяете DP `ZoomLevel` (или `CumulatedScroll`, если хотите использовать не только для zoom'а), обновляете значение в code behind. Теперь во внешнем контроле включаете `Canvas` и поверх `ZoomControl`, затем `ZoomLevel` из VM биндите на `ZoomLevel` из `ZoomControl`.

Таким образом вы сможете использовать `ZoomControl` и в другом месте, независимо от наличия `Canvas`'а.

Comment: > Я имел в виду такой вариант: вы наследуетесь от UserControl (пусть будет ZoomControl), в ZoomControl определяете DP ZoomLevel (или CumulatedScroll, если хотите использовать не только для zoom'а), обновляете значение в code behind.

Если я сделаю так, то каким образом смогу отследить, что скроллинг осуществляется именно над канвасом?

Comment: @sp7: Ну например:

    <Grid>
        <Canvas/>
        <local:ZoomControl ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel}"/>
    </Grid>

Comment: Что-то я не понял, как это будет работать. Свойство ZoomLevel биндится к свойству ZoomLevel нашей VM, это хорошо. Но как свойство ZoomLevel  будет узнавать, что произошло событие MouseWheel над канвасом? Ведь мне нужно обновлять значение ZoomLevel именно когда произошло событие у канваса, а каким образом связан ZoomControl и Canvas не понятно.

Comment: @sp7: Ну, `ZoomControl` геометрически расположен там же, где и `Canvas`. Так что между «над канвасом» и «над `ZoomControl`» — это одно и то же.

Comment: > Ну, ZoomControl геометрически расположен там же, где и Canvas. Так что между «над канвасом» и «над ZoomControl» — это одно и то же.

Подразумевается, что оба элемента расположены в одной и той же ячейке грида, например с координатами Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1". За счет этого реализуется эффект наложения?

Comment: @sp7: Именно так.

Если у вас в контроле нет `Grid`'а, а нужно расположить два элемента один над другим, надо добавить простой `Grid` как в комментарии двухчасовой давности.